# Dividing a row by reference value in mysql

Tags: mysql, row, division

Please help me.

Here is the raw data:

```
uid | id | value | 
1   |  a |   389 |
2   |  b |   201 |
3   |  c |   170 |
```

if.... When the reference value is '200'

How do you get it to come out like this?

mysql..

```
no| uid | id | value | cut 
1 |  1  |  a |   200 | 200
2 |  1  |  a |   189 | 200
3 |  2  |  b |   200 | 200
4 |  2  |  b |     1 | 200
5 |  3  |  c |   170 | 200
```

help me!!!!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If one of the rows had a value of, say, "500", would you expect to see three rows ("200", "200", "100") in the result, or two rows ("200" and "300")?

Comment: @dtanabe 3rows .. need rows

Comment: @belwood I created a pivot table and inserted the data

I read it again.

PHP+MYSQL+JQUERY...

The browser took time out .. die...!!

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Recursive CTEs are the most straightforward I can think of to accomplish this, but they are only available in MySQL 8.

Comment: @dtanabe  im sad... my.. mysql 4.1.2

Comment: yikes; then I agree with @belwood; best to do it in your PHP app instead of trying to do it in SQL. I doubt it's possible with MySQL 4 without more creativity than it's really worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
SET @row_num = 0;

SELECT (@row_num := @row_num + 1) AS "no",uid,id,valueA, "200" as cut FROM
(SELECT uid,id,IF(valueA/200 > 1,200,valueA) AS "valueA" FROM tableA UNION ALL
SELECT uid,id,IF(valueA/200 > 2,200,valueA-200) AS "valueA" FROM tableA UNION ALL
SELECT uid,id,IF(valueA/200 > 3,200,valueA-400) AS "valueA" FROM tableA) a 
WHERE valueA > 0
ORDER BY uid,id,valueA DESC;
```

If valueA divide by 200 equal to more than 1, it will return 200, otherwise it will only return what's in valueA. That's the first syntax among the `UNION ALL` queries.

The second one I added another condition to as if valueA divided by 200 IS NOT equal to more than 2, it will return valueA-200. You can try to execute the `UNION ALL` queries to see the results.

It's not the best way to do it and I am sure that there are better solution out there but I got it working using this method. You might use this as temporary solution or at least give you some ideas.

Comment: thank you!!! very very.. thank U.. Your god will bless you.. 124 lines were replaced with 8 lines

Comment: glad I could help @michaelkwon ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySQL 8 or later, Recursive CTEs can help:

```
CREATE DATABASE test;
USE test;
CREATE TABLE TestData (uid INTEGER, id VARCHAR(8), value INTEGER);
INSERT INTO TestData VALUES (1, 'a', 389);
INSERT INTO TestData VALUES (2, 'b', 201);
INSERT INTO TestData VALUES (3, 'c', 170);
INSERT INTO TestData VALUES (4, 'd', 550);

-- Set up an auto-incrementing row number
SET @row_num = 0;
WITH RECURSIVE cte (uid, id, value, remainder) AS (
  -- start with a copy of the table, but adding another column for the value that is at most 200
  SELECT a.uid, a.id, LEAST(a.value, 200), a.value AS "remainder" FROM TestData a
  UNION
  -- repeatedly select from the previous result set, meanwhile decrementing the "remainder" column
  SELECT uid, id, LEAST(remainder - 200, 200), remainder - 200 FROM cte WHERE remainder > 200
)
-- select the actual data that we care about
SELECT (@row_num := @row_num + 1) AS no, uid, id, value, 200 AS "cut" FROM cte ORDER BY id, value DESC;
```

This results in the following table:

```
no | uid | id | value | cut
1  |  1  |  a |  200  | 200
2  |  1  |  a |  189  | 200
3  |  2  |  b |  200  | 200
4  |  2  |  b |    1  | 200
5  |  3  |  c |  170  | 200
6  |  4  |  d |  200  | 200
7  |  4  |  d |  200  | 200
8  |  4  |  d |  150  | 200
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing a stored procedure instead of doing this all in pure SQL or just select the rows from the table and do the following in php:

From my understanding, you're looking for this:

```
no = 1
For each row in the result set
    for i = 0 to int(value/cut)
        output the row with value set to cut
        no += 1
    output the row with value set to mod(value, cut)
    no += 1
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm looking for a query. Server load is large in other parts. very very.. thank..In your interest